# Finding data according to relevency and then take 2 result from diff domain

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-error-1054

I am having so much domain name in my DB, for example

```
www.yahoo.com/duniya.html
www.yahoo.com/hero.html
www.123musiq.com/
www.123musiq.com/home.html
www.123musiq.com/horo.html
www.123musiq.com/yuva.html
www.sensongs.com/
www.sensongs.com/hindi.html
www.sensongs.com/yuva.html
www.sensongs.com/duniya.html
www.sensongs.pk/duniya1.html
```

i need to sort them like,first 2 from yahoo,then next 2 from 123musiq then next 2 from sensongs.
how can i do that? in mysql or PHP?
i know to get the domain name,i need to know how to sort 2 from each domain?
i am using match against method

Expecting output

```
 
    www.yahoo.com/duniya.html
    www.yahoo.com/hero.html
    www.123musiq.com/
    www.123musiq.com/home.html
    www.sensongs.com/
    www.sensongs.com/hindi.html
```

I Use following Code

```
SELECT x.url
  FROM (SELECT t.url,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1) THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                 ELSE @rownum := 1
               END AS rank,
               @domain := SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1)
          FROM URL2 t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @domain := '') r
      ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1)) X
 WHERE x.rank <= 2 AND MATCH(teet,url,html) AGAINST ('account');
```

It Showing Error

```
Query : SELECT x.url   FROM (SELECT t.url,                CASE                   WHEN @domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1) THEN @row...
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'teet' in 'where clause'
```

But Teet is a Column in my URL2 Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have analytic functions, which is what you'd need to get the two entries per grouping.  The other pain is the "www." complicates locating the 2nd period...

Use:

```
SELECT x.url
  FROM (SELECT t.url,
               t.teet,
               t.html,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1) THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                 ELSE @rownum := 1
               END AS rank,
               @domain := SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1)
          FROM URL2 t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @domain := '') r
      ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.url, '/', 1)) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 2
```

Comment: @OMG: we can find the domain by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521094/how-we-can-find-domain-name-using-mysql-and-regular-expression ,wht is x.domainname,x.rank,t.domainname

Comment: @Alex Mathew: Thx, updated. `x` is the table alias for the derived table/inline view.  It's used the same way as the `t` alias is in that derived table/inline view...

Comment: @OMG: My table name is url2 and coloum name for saving url is url,can u rewrite the SQL?

Comment: @Alex Mathew: I don't understand what you mean by "MATCH AGAINST IT is Showing error" - what error #?  And can you update the question to show how you are attempting to use the query regarding the "MATCH AGAINST"?

Comment: @Alex Mathew: The derived table only contains two columns--`url` and `rank`.  Assuming they exist in the `URL2` table, you need to expose them in the derived table for them to be visible to the FTS MATCH/AGAINST clause you listed - see update.

Comment: @OMG:I am Not a DB DEVELOPER, i am just a PHP Programmer, can you please update the query with MATCH/AGAINST,I tried but it is showing there no column name t.url,but it is in the INDEX

Comment: @Alex Mathew: I'm trying to help as best I can, but you have to provide details about what you want and what you are trying to do--I'm not psychic.  If you want to access the `url` column outside of the `FROM` clause, you need to use the "x" alias...

Comment: @OMG: i check that with x alias it showing error, Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: @Alex Mathew: Have you created a Full Text Index for each of the columns in that list? IE: `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ft_url_idx ON URL2(url)`

Comment: @OMG: i create FULLTEXT for 3 columns (url,teet,html) in the name "SEARCH"

Comment: @Alex Mathew: Do you still get the missing full text index error?   Where did this full text search requirement come from?  It wasn't originally in this question, nor the previous one.

Comment: @OMG: Ya,i am still getting the missing full text index, actually i forget to add this INDEX need first,sorry

Comment: @Alex Mathew: I'm grasping at straws, but you could move the Full Text search into the inner query... but that would affect the rank values, because the rank would be only those that match based on the full text - currently it's ranking based on the domain name.

Comment: @Alex Mathew: Does the full text search work as: `SELECT * FROM URL2 WHERE MATCH (url,teet,html) AGAINST ('account')`?  If it does, gradually tack on stuff from the inner query until you get the error again.  Beyond that, I'd post a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/) about the issue - you'll need to provide sample data & the query as examples to see if others can replicate the issue before it can be addressed.