# Mysql query to extract domains from urls

Tags: mysql

sorry for my english

i have this query to extract domain from urls

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(url, LOCATE('/', url, 8) - 1), 8) AS domain...
```

it works only when the url is like www.google.com/something

it doesn't work with urls like

www.google.it (without trailing slash)

www.google.it/abc/xzy/ (permalink)

do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least very much alike): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521094/how-we-can-find-domain-name-using-mysql-and-regular-expression

Answer (score 65):

I had to combine some of the previous answers , plus a little more hackery for my data set . This is what works for me , it returns the domain and any sub-domains:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1) AS domain
```

Explanation ( cause non-trivial SQL rarely makes sense ):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_url, '/', 3)` - strips any path if the url has a protocol
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(THAT, '://', -1)` - strips any protocol from THAT
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(THAT, '/', 1)` - strips any path from THAT ( if there was no protocol )
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(THAT, '?', 1)` - strips the query string from THAT ( if there was no path or trailing / )

Test Cases:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1) AS domain
FROM ( 
    SELECT       'http://test.com' as target_url 
    UNION SELECT 'https://test.com' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://test.com/one' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://test.com/?huh' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://test.com?http://ouch.foo' 
    UNION SELECT 'test.com' 
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two/three'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two/three?u=http://maaaaannn'
    UNION SELECT 'http://one.test.com'
    UNION SELECT 'one.test.com/one'
    UNION SELECT 'two.one.test.com/one' ) AS Test;
```

Results:

```
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'test.com'
'one.test.com'
'one.test.com'
'two.one.test.com'
```

Comment: worked perfectly for random values in the url field, including non urls, thanks

Comment: it also match www as subdomain.

Comment: interesting , what input did you use ? I'll look into it .

Comment: just a minor point. we had urls like "//test.com/test.html" and it didn't work with those. using '//' instead of '://' made it work.

Comment: Works great. I wrapped the whole thing with a REPLACE to remove the www:

`REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1),'www.','')`

Comment: how to get only main domain, dont want to include subdomains, like in the example in your answer, all resultant rows should be `test.com`

Comment: Slight variation I find useful to remove whitespace too: 
`TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1)) AS domain`

Answer (score 19):

remove www., anysubdomain and everything after /:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'http://', -1)), '/', 1)), '.', -2) as domain
```

Comment: Used this one, worked fine after I changed 'http://' into '://' allowing for https.

Comment: Sorry, this one does not work with domains with double dots, like api.site.com

Comment: When you have both http and https in your field you can use something like  
`CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(url,1,5) = 'https'
  THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'https://', -1)), '/', 1)), '.', -2)
 ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'http://', -1)), '/', 1)), '.', -2)
 END`

Comment: @Redithion thank you sir. So happened to save me some time today had to up vote this answer

Answer (score 7):

**If you want to remove www. along with http://, https:// and /(path) from your domain please do this:**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(document_url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1),'www.',-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

All the answers do not seem to work for me. For example, a url that starts variables with a ? fails for some answers. This works for me for all kinds of URLs:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(url), 'https://', ''), 'http://', ''), '/', 1), '?', 1) AS domain;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the first occurrence of `/` why are you passing 8 into `LOCATE` as the starting position? (I assume to skip slashes after the protocol such as http:// but if you also expect url's without a protocol, consider short ones like cnn.com/page)

```
IF(LOCATE('/', url) > 0, SUBSTRING(url, 1, LOCATE('/', url) - 1), url) AS domain
```

Alternatively:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 1) AS domain
```

The latter seems easier to me.

Answer (score 2):

For my case this worked fine:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'//',-1),'www.',''),'/',1) AS DOMAIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works well on my very messy data:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(url, '//', '.'), '/', 1), '.', -2) AS Domain
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(URL, '://', -1),'/',1) as DOMAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple examples on this page (and some documentation) [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) to make the following, annotated, version. It appears impossible with SUBSTRING_INDEX to remove subdomains without removing *.co.uk type domains.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 
'?', 1), # split on url params to remove weirdest stuff first 
'://', -1), # remove protocal http:// https:// ftp:// ...
'/', 1), # split on path 
':', 2), # split on user:pass
'@', 1), # split on user:port@
':', 1), # split on port
'www.', -1), # remove www.
'.', 4), # keep TLD + domain name
'/', 1) 
AS domain
FROM ( 
    SELECT       'http://test.com' as url 
    UNION SELECT 'https://test.com' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://test.com/one' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://test.com/?huh' 
    UNION SELECT 'http://www.test1.test.com?http://ouch.foo' 
    UNION SELECT 'test.com' 
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two/three'
    UNION SELECT 'test.com/one/two/three?u=http://maaaaannn'
    UNION SELECT 'http://one.test.com'
    UNION SELECT 'one.test.com/one'
    UNION SELECT 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
    UNION SELECT 'http://a.very.complex-domain.co.uk:8080/foo/bar'
    UNION SELECT 'postgres://user:pass@host.com:5432/path?k=v#f'
    UNION SELECT 'http://10.64.3.5/data_check/index.php?r=index/rawdatacheck'
    UNION SELECT 'two.one.test.com/one' ) AS test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to account for no trailing '/'

```
IF( LOCATE('/', replace(url,'http://', '') ) > 0 , SUBSTRING(replace(url,'http://', ''), 1, LOCATE('/', replace(url,'http://', '') ) - 1), replace(url,'http://', '')) AS domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use it as it will also capture url like "www.google.co.in"

```
SELECT replace((replace((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(url, '//', ''), '/', 1), '*', -2)), 'http:','')),'https:','') AS Domain
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of installing MySQL extensions (UDFs), then there's a UDF you can use that does exactly this while respecting different top-level domains like "google.com" and "google.co.uk"

https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/mysql-get-etld-p1

```
select`get_etld_p1`('http://a.very.complex-domain.co.uk:8080/foo/bar');-- 'complex-domain.co.uk'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://www.bbc.co.uk/');-- 'bbc.co.uk'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://github.com/StirlingMarketingGroup/');-- 'github.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('https://localhost:10000/index');-- 'localhost'
select`get_etld_p1`('android-app://com.google.android.gm');-- 'com.google.android.gm'
select`get_etld_p1`('example.test.domain.com');-- 'domain.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('postgres://user:pass@host.com:5432/path?k=v#f');-- 'host.com'
select`get_etld_p1`('exzvk.omsk.so-ups.ru');-- 'so-ups.ru'
select`get_etld_p1`('http://10.64.3.5/data_check/index.php?r=index/rawdatacheck');-- '10.64.3.5'
select`get_etld_p1`('not a domain');-- null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(website, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1),'www.',-1)
```

removes
http://
https://
www.

and combinations of them.

Leaves domian.com and sub.domian.com combinations.