# Mysql Extract URL from LONG_TEXT using SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, facebook, substring, html-content-extraction, locate

The HTML content of my page is located in a **LONG_TEXT** column in MySQL.

My objectif is **to extract the url of my facebook page** using the `LOCATE`, `SUBSTRING` or `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions in **MySQL**

I found this article [Mysql query to extract domains from urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280336/mysql-query-to-extract-domains-from-urls) but it doesn't really fit the problem.

How would you extract efficiently the string between `'href="http://www.facebook.com/'` and `'"'` in the string using mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works but can certainly be improved

```
IF(LOCATE('http://www.facebook.com/', html_cache) > 0, CONCAT('http://www.facebook.com/', SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(html_cache, 'http://www.facebook.com/', -1)), '"', 1)), html_cache) AS page_url
```