# Is there a solution of parsing domains of URLs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

Table1:

```
ID  URL
1   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a6a2sxy.aspx
2   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mysql
3   http://wrong-url
4   http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/042599i.html
5   http://www.chami.com
```

I want to add a column to record the domains of the URLS.
I want to get a table like this:

```
ID  URL                                                        Domain
1   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a6a2sxy.aspx      microsoft.com
2   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/mysql                         wikipedia.org
3   http://wrong-url                                           null
4   http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/042599i.html            chami.com
5   http://www.chami.com                                       chami.com
```

Anyone can provide a solution?

Comment: MySQL saves and queries the data. It does not parse it. Languages that are meant for computation and not data querying are used to parse domains or any other info prior to inserting it into database.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280336/mysql-query-to-extract-domains-from-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(url, '/', 3), substring_index, '.', -2) as domain
```

This doesn't work for the third example.  For that, use a `case` to detect the pattern.  Something like:

```
select (case when url like 'http//%.%.%/%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(url, '/', 3), substring_index, '.', -2)
        end) as domain
```