# How to remove subdomain from url in mysql?

Tags: mysql, url, text-parsing

I found a similar question on this page [Mysql query to extract domains from urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280336/mysql-query-to-extract-domains-from-urls)

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(target_url, '/', 3), '://', -1), '/', 1), '?', 1) AS domain
```

But the result of this code is not correct

> 'www.abc.com' 'lalala.one.google.com' 'two.one.test.com'

I need to get the 2 last words, separator is dot.

I need this result

> 'abc.com' 'google.com' 'test.com'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `subtring()` and `substring_index()`:

```
set @url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937363/how-to-remove-subdomain-from-url-in-mysql';
select substring_index(substring_index(substring(@url, locate('://', @url) + 3), '/', 1), '.', -2) as domain
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohEEKRwg7wyTXX3vXQuFnd/0).
Result:

```
domain
-----------------
stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaa.bbb.sss.google.com','.',-2);
```

Comment: This worked well to extract the basedomain from a sub-domain.