# GROUP BY multiple text matches within one column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Given data like:

```
URL
some_url.com
some_url.com
some_url.co.uk
some_other_url.com
some_other_url.co.uk
some_other_url.co.uk
some_other_url.org
```

is there a way to construct a query that will result in;

```
some_url         3
some_other_url   4
```

Currently I'm either using a standard group by url or I query the aggregations one by one using LIKE
Is there a way to do this in one query? (using mysql currently, but will be moving this data over to postgresql)

Would it be better practice to add a column to reflect this grouping (at insert time)? (this feels redundant but would be best performing I guess)

EDIT:
data can contain www and non-www as well as http, https. Also I'll have to do similar thing on other columns that contain (free) text values.

Comment: You don't have http or https protocols in your data, right?

Comment: Yes there will be https and https in there as well as www and non-www domains. 
Also, need to apply this on other columns that contain 'free text' so that's why I was looking at LIKE for text matching

Comment: have posted an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values can have http, https and www, and may be query string too, you will have to clean all such values first before grouping it. Took the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280336/mysql-query-to-extract-domains-from-urls) and modified it to match your requirement.

```
SELECT url, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3),
                '://', -1),
            '/', 1),
        '?', 1),
    'www.', -1),
'.', 1) AS domain,
COUNT(1)
FROM tblname
GROUP BY domain;
```

Comment: thanks. the first url should not be there I think?
I still have a problem now with the subdomains, but will look into a solution using CASE most likely to get those included if they are present.

Comment: Yes first column url is just for the reference purpose, you can add remove columns from SELECT statement as needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is ANSI SQL compliant and should probably work with both MySQL and Postgresql:

```
select url, count(*)
from
(
    select substring(url from 1 for position('.' in url) -1) as url
    from tablename
) dt
group by url
```

Using `position()` to find the first `.` character. Do `substring()` and finally `GROUP BY` the result.

Answer (score 2):

use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in mysql which help you substring from a string before a specified number of occurrences of the delimiter.

```
select count(*) as cnt, SUBSTRING_INDEX(c,'.',1) as val from cte
group by  SUBSTRING_INDEX(c,'.',1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Postgesql:

```
select split_part(url,'.',1) g,count(*) 
from url_table 
group by  g 
order by g;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni