# MySQL SELECT rows that match a domain in URL column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a list of URLs where I want to limit the daily use for each domain using URL column that contain the full link.

If the number of daily usages exceeds 10 it won't execute the request.

Now I'm doing it like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$query = "SELECT type FROM websites WHERE url=? and date=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$url,$strdate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

The above will limit the daily usage for specific page/full URL link and not by domain.

**I want to count the rows in URLs column that contains that domain.**

Comment: I think part of the problem is you're generating SQL queries by using string concatenation instead of using prepared (parameterized) queries: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll check that, but the query is working for page's URL. What i want is to write a query check for domains, but I don't know how to check all URLs in the URL column for specific domain!

Comment: I've updated the post to comply with using prepared queries. Still, I don't know how this related to my Question! Thank you.

Comment: Your code is still insecure (look up: **SQL injection**) because you are not using parametrized variables. You have merely upgraded the code without any improvement. Highly recommend you get acquainted with best practices, just you don't get hacked within minutes of putting this code into production. It' still not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps you just need an additional field to serve as **incremented counter**? And perhaps the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) PHP function can help you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a list of URLs where I want to limit the daily use for each website by domain not full URL link. I want to do that by a query, and don't think Parse_url can be used here

Comment: The answers here might help. You can apply that logic (from one of these answers or something similar) to the url before doing the comparison.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280336/mysql-query-to-extract-domains-from-urls (And you should do it in a parameterized query, as mentioned above.)

Comment: Thank you. but as I said I already searched stack overflow, the answers above not always working correctly.

Comment: Again, I modified the code to follow your security directions. I hope it's perfect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking apart the URL column to check just the domain is quite inefficient.  This because the only way to do it is to scan the entire table every time and check every row.

So instead, make sure you have the desired data in separate columns and have a suitable index.  From what you have said, I suggest adding an extra column

```
domain VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

and populate it *as the rows are being inserted into the table*.

Another issue is "daily count of 10".  Is that "today, midnight to midnight"?  If so, in whose timezone, the server's or the clients?  Or perhaps you mean "in the last 24 hours".  If the latter, then the query becomes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites
    WHERE domain = ?
      and date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

That will deliver a scalar value; check it for being < 10.

(Note:  That test works regardless of the data type of `date` (DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, etc), but will have minor hiccups twice a year as daylight saving turns on or off.)

For efficiency the table should have

```
INDEX(domain, date)
```

I'm puzzled as to why there is no test for `user_id`.  Is there only one "user" of your site?  Or maybe the limit of 10 applies ot everyone *combined*?  If you do add such a test (`AND user_id = ?`), then the index becomes `(user_id, domain, date)`

Comment: Excellent. I think I will create another table for that with domain, and date fields. Partial data repetition but faster process. Now I'm using string for the date yyyymmdd (server date), and the tools my website provides are free with no subscription. What you think?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai - I think that dates should be of type `DATE`, not varchar or integer, but it does not impact the discussion.  What "tools" are relevant?  Are the tools preventing you from adding a column?

Comment: Nothing is preventing adding another column to same table, but I was thinking that this table should only keep the domains for current day (today). While auto delete the previous dates. What do you think?

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai - "autodelete"?  That sounds like extra work.  With a good index, extra rows in the table _may_ not be important.