# How to fetch Domain names from Urls in MySql

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How we can find domain name using MySQL and regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521094/how-we-can-find-domain-name-using-mysql-and-regular-expression)

My db table has a column called url which contains info like:
http://xyz.com/cat/index/?page=2
http://www.google.com/webmaster.php
http://yahoo.com/dsdsd/category.aspx
etc.

I want to just fetch their domain names like:
xyz.com
google.com
yahoo.com

How should I write the query in mysql to get the above result.

Please help.

Answer (score 8):

Someone in Digital Point gave me the answer

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(url, "http://", ""), "www.", ""), '/', 1);
```