# How to copy rows from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here the structure of `table_1`:

```
id, website, time, status
25296171, http://example.com/login.php, 2015-12-26 00:49:06, NEW
25296172, http://www.stackoverflow.com/sample.html, 2015-12-26 01:25:29, NEW
25296173, https://britain.co.uk/fwef/wefwef/eep, 2015-12-26 01:26:05, NEW
25296174, http://subdomain.hello.net/random.php, 2015-12-26 01:27:05, NEW
```

What I'd like to do is copy all rows in this table that have their `status` set to `NEW` and copy them to the `table_2` table.  Here's the 2 things I'm trying to accomplish:

1. As each row is copied over, I'd like to change the `status` from  `NEW` to `COMPLETE`.
2. I'd like to strip the URL and output just the domain in a new column.

Here's an example of what `table_2` would look like:

```
id, domain, website, time, status
25296171, example.com, http://example.com/login.php, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW
25296172, stackoverflow.com, http://www.stackoverflow.com/sample.html, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW
25296173, britain.co.uk, https://britain.co.uk/fwef/wefwef/eep, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW
25296174, hello.net, http://subdomain.hello.net/random.php, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW
```

I know it's possible to simply copy tables over.  I guess where I'm getting confused it how I can strip the URL to just show the domain and then update the status for that row in `table_1`.

By the way, I'm trying to have this all handled in PHP.

Might be a newbie question, sorry if so.  Just trying to work on a site and can't quite figure this out.

Comment: My advice is to try to perform the operation in mysql as it is faster (no need to fetch the data, change + insert in second table). URL stripping can be done by considering the substring between :// and the first / after that, but it might give results in cases like http://domain:port/page

Comment: A good detailed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy all data with new fields:

Here is the example how to get all needed data for table_2 **[SQlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077cff/13)**

```
INSERT INTO table_2 
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(website, 'http://', ''), '/', 1),website,status 
FROM table_1 
WHERE status="NEW"

AND Update table_1  

UPDATE table_1 SET status="COMPLETED" where id in ( SELECT id from table_2 )
```

Comment: Yea... that's not going to work.  It doesn't include the new column `domain`.  Also, that's selecting rows with a status that is set to `COMPLETE`.  I need to select rows that are `NEW` and then change the status in `table_1` to `COMPLETE` after they've been copied to `table_2`.

Comment: I know brother.you can use [link/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521094/how-we-can-find-domain-name-using-mysql-and-regular-expression?lq=1[/link]

Comment: When I run that, I'm getting error `#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: Actually figured that out - after `website` there should be the `time` column.

Comment: yea bro I have tested in sqlfiddle so have to omit that

Comment: Hmm - there's only 2 issues I'm seeing with it.  (1) It's only removing `http` and not also removing `https`.  It's also not removing www either.

(2) It's changing the `status` of the rows in `table_2` to `COMPLETED`.  Those rows should have a status of `NEW`.  The rows that should be changed to `COMPLETED` are the ones in `table_1` that were copied.

Comment: If u r using php as u mentioned in question than no need to use mysql function in queries handle this with php