# Extract hostname from an URL in MySQL with REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to extract hostnames from URLs by using the MySQL function `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

The closest RegEx I got is the following:

`(?:\w+\.)?(\w+\.\w+)`

Which works relatively speaking, but the issue is that the captured hostname is **grouped**

Suppose we're trying to match `https://www.w3schools.com/home`, the above regex would return:

1. *Full match* `www.w3schools.com`
2. *Group 1.* `w3schools.com`

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` seems to only subtract what is found in the *"Full match"* thus the above solution results incorrect.
How can I modify the above pattern in order to include the hostname in the Full match, rather than a Group?

Comment: Tip: Hostnames can and will have `-` in them.

Comment: This pattern `(?:\w+\.)?(\w+\.\w+)` is a very broad match for a url. It matches word characters with a dot in between.

Comment: You should precise what MySQL version you have. Is it version 8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How we can find domain name using MySQL and regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521094/how-we-can-find-domain-name-using-mysql-and-regular-expression)

Comment: @AndyLester no, the question is REGEXP oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the MySQL is version 8, use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\\w+\\.\\w+(?=/|$)')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/e3trQA/1)

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: It fails on URLS like https://www.w3schools.com/home?refer=www.referredby.com, as it matches both. But overall the solution seems great. Any way you can prevent the above case scenario?

Comment: @Constantin The code in the answer cannot match both. `REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\\w+\\.\\w+(?=/|$)')` returns the first occurrence by default. Also, please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/W2eajd/1.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me but this worked fine for my purposes:

`REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(proof, 'http.*?://.*?/'), 'www.', '')`